# WP REST API V2 custom field convert data to an array

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I've registered a couple of custom fields to be printed out by WP REST API v2's endpoint for a custom post type. I can get the data to print out for me to consume in my app but I would like to change the format of the data that is outputted. I used the toolset plugin to create multiline custom field. In that field I stored the following format:

`bead, 1, 2 | bead1 3, 14 | bead2, 24, 43`

this goes on and on for about 60 'beads'. I want to output this though:

`[{bead: 1, 2}, {bead1: 3, 14}...]`

I created my the code to output the format as it comes out from the field:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_custom_fields'); 

function register_custom_fields(){
  register_rest_field(
    'rosary_prayers',
    'prayer',
    array(
      'get_callback' => 'show_fields'
      )
    );

  register_rest_field(
    'rosary_prayers',
    'prayerlist',
    array(
      'get_callback' => 'show_fields'
      )
    );


}


function show_fields($object, $field_name, $request){
  $field_name = 'wpcf-' . $field_name; 
  return get_post_meta($object['id'], $field_name, true);
}
```

Is there any way that I can "catch" the `prayerlist` and explode and reconstruct to the format? Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a bit of detail went in to my solution.

here's the final code even though I changed the output format of the original question:

```
function show_fields($object, $field_name, $request){
  $field_name = 'wpcf-' . $field_name;
  $value = get_post_meta($object['id'], $field_name, true);
  if($field_name == 'wpcf-prayerlist'){
    $result = array();
    $value = str_replace( ' ', '', $value );
    $pieces1 = explode( '|', $value );

    foreach ( $pieces1 as $piece1 ) {
        // $piece1 = cross, 1, 2
        $pcs = explode( ',', $piece1 );
        $pcss = array ( $pcs[0], intval( $pcs[1] ), intval( $pcs[2] ) );

        $result[] = $pcss;
    }
    $value = $result;
  }
  return $value;
}
```

The gists of it all is that you "catch" the data inside your show_fields function and you manipulate it there based on the field you want manipulate.

Very powerful stuff WordPress! Great way to expand and build your REST API.